# Facebook App - If the user does not have sufficient credits balance want to proceed with my own payment method

Tags: facebook

For my facebook Application subscribe using **facebook credits** If the user does not have sufficient credits balance want getout from facebook payment to want to proceed with my own payment method

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/credits/

Here in facebook docs not given any method for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the facebook rules we cant retrieve the user credit balance, facebook doesn't gave that credits balance checking option to the App...

Comment: Well, that’s understandable, for privacy reasons … how much “money” I have in whatever kind of account, may it be real or just “virtual”, is nothing that third parties should have access to easily.

Answer (score 1):

If the app is a game, what you're suggesting is explicitly against policy.
If it isn't a game, you could detect that the user exited the pay dialog without completing a purchase and show them alternative options to receive the item/service

Comment: How can i get the documentation for this? Is there any code available in the net?

Comment: Code to check if the user closed the dialog?  See the 'Return Data' section of the documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/pay/ - 'error' 1383010 is returned if the user cancels

Comment: Before the pay dialog, can check user credits balance?, if credits balance does not have sufficient shall i can use EBS payment? this check will be before pay dialog... @lgy